# while doing vagrant up vm is not initialing getting error in INFO subprocess

Tags: devops, vagrant-windows, concourse

while doing vagrant up vm is not initialing  getting error in  INFO subprocess:

> Starting process: ["C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell rofile", "-NonInteractive", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command", "(new-ob cipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Sy ]::Administrator)"]  INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment... in debug mode 
>   command :  vagrant init concourse/lite create a file but while doing vagrant up nothing is happening .
>
> virtual box version :-Version 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2)
>   windows:7 .

as i am new to this thing a step by step procedure would help a lot .

Comment: So where is the `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: its done @BMV thanks for asking actually the issue is i am using upper version of virtual box and lower verion of vagrant thats why it is not picking up the virtual box , once i degrade the virtual box then it is working fine ...

Comment: If you fixed your problem, and think it is a good solution, you can answer your question directly, more than put in comment.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
actually the issue is i am using upper version of virtual box and lower verion of vagrant that is  why it is not picking up the virtual box , once i degrade the virtual box then it is working fine